# Method for Sorting 2D Matricies, How can i make the method generic?

Tags: c#

```
public static void Sort2DArray(int[,] matrix)
{
    var numb = new int[matrix.GetLength(0) * matrix.GetLength(1)];

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var n in matrix)
    {
        numb[i] = n;
        i++;
    }
    Array.Sort(numb);

    int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = numb[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm curious how can I make this method generic. I wish that it could sort double matrices, string matrices and so on and so forth.

Comment: Unrelated but you can write `numb[i++] = n;` or `matrix[i, j] = numb[k++];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. the method looks like this:

```
    public static void Sort2DArray<T>(T[,] matrix)
    {
        var numb = new T[matrix.GetLength(0) * matrix.GetLength(1)];

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var n in matrix)
        {
            numb[i] = n;
            i++;
        }
        Array.Sort(numb);

        int k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = numb[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IComparable` interface as a generic type `T` specifier.

Comment: Thanks. I Already solved it. this Question was kind of a test. I have never asked any questions in SO.

Answer (score 1):

See those links

1. [How to Sort 2D Array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866414/how-to-sort-2d-array-in-c-sharp)
2. [How do I sort a two-dimensional array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232395/how-do-i-sort-a-two-dimensional-array-in-c)
3. http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=151