# C# program to sort a two dimensional array elements in ascending order?(sort the columns first and then the rows)

Tags: c#

```
public void ascendingOrder()
{
    // helper class
    double temp = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])
            {
                temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                numbers[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i need the code to sort the columns first and then sort the rows like the following example!

input :

> n=3

```
2 2 1 
3 53 4 
32 5 3
```

output:

```
1 2 2 
3 3 54 
4 32 53
```

Comment: there's some inconsistency with your output

Comment: input: n=3? And what is that suppose to mean?

Comment: Why you just not use Array.Sort and then if you want Reverse?!

Comment: Your program operates on one dimensional `numbers` array. Are we supposed to extend you that program for two dimensional arrays? That is not how Stack Overflow works...

Comment: i can't see a two dimensional array here?

Comment: first correct the output, numbers are different from what we see in input.

Answer (score 1):

Some helpful links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/166236/Sorting-a-Two-Dimensional-Array-in-Csharp
- [How to Sort 2D Array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866414/how-to-sort-2d-array-in-c-sharp)
- [How do I sort a two-dimensional array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232395/how-do-i-sort-a-two-dimensional-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = new int[] { 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 };
Array.Sort<int>(array,
                new Comparison<int>(
                        (i1, i2) => i1.CompareTo(i2)
                ));
```

[Better way to sort array in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430016/better-way-to-sort-array-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this person is currently writing an exam, so linq methods will not make him pass this test. 
Try with this code.

```
        double[,] numbers = new double[,]{ { 1, 3, 2 }, { 4, 6, 5 }, { 7, 9, 8 } };
        // helper class
        double temp = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    if (numbers[k,i] < numbers[k,j])
                    {
                        temp = numbers[k,i];
                        numbers[k,i] = numbers[k,j];
                        numbers[k,j] =temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And how rewriting an answer will help him to learn something? Aren't exams for such purpose?

Comment: Let him learn the hard way once he finds a job.