# sort 2d Array re-order the first column

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

For example:

```
Array
ID | Primary | Data2
------------------
1  | N       | Something 1
2  | N       | Something 2
3  | Y       | Something 3
```

I'm trying to sort it based on the primary column and I want the "Y" to show first. It should bring all the other column at the top.

The end result would be:

```
Sorted Array
ID | Primary | Data2
------------------
3  | Y       | Something 3
1  | N       | Something 1
2  | N       | Something 2
```

Is there a pre-made function for that. If not, how do we do this?

It is declared like this:

```
Dim Array(,) As String
```

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using LINQ's [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.orderby(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`ThenBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534743(v=vs.100).aspx) to order collections of objects.  You just pass in a selector function to use to order the collections.  For example:

```
orderedObjs = objs.OrderByDescending(function(x) x.isPrimary).ThenBy(function(x) x.id).ToList()
```

This code orders a collection first by the `.isPrimary` boolean, then by the `id`.  Finally, it immediately evaluates the query into a List and assigns it to some variable.

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SFfUEH)

Comment: Working like a charm. Had to tweak it a bit to make it work. This is a great way to accomplish this. I have to modify the logic in the software cause i was not using object before. It is better that way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar [C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866414/how-to-sort-2d-array-in-c-sharp) whose solution applies just as well to VB. In short, you can use [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3.aspx) of `Array.Sort` if you first split your 2D array into separate (1D) arrays:

```
Dim Primary() As String
Dim Data2() As String
// ...
Array.Sort(Primary,Data2)
```

This would reorder `Data2` according to the Y/N sort of `Primary`, after which point you could then recombine them into a 2D array.